# How to know if an RDF graph is lean?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, blank-nodes

I just discovered the definition of a [lean graph](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#dfn-lean) and I don't always know how to define it and if someone can explain to me if this graphs are lean or not .

```
G1 :
_:X foaf:knows ex:bob
_:X foaf:knows _:Y
```

> I think this is lean !

```
G2:    
_:X foaf:knows ex:bob
_:X foaf:knows _:X
```

> G2 isn't lean !

```
G3
_:X foaf:knows ex:bob
```

> I don't know XD

```
G4
_:X foaf:knows _:X
```

> And I don't know XD

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Graphs with only one triple or with no anonymous nodes are always lean - nothing can be removed without information loss, unless the triple can be inferred. That will change depending on what reasoner you use, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example at https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#dfn-lean

> For example, the graph
>
> ex:a ex:p _:x .
>   _:y ex:p _:x .
>
> is not lean, but
>
> ex:a ex:p _:x .
>   _:x ex:p _:x .
>
> is lean. Ground graphs are lean.

In the question examples subject and object are flipped but otherwise G1 and G2 are the "RDF 1.1 Semantics" examples.

G1 is not lean.

You can remove "_:X foaf:knows _:Y" (or remove "_:y ex:p _:x") - that triple adds no new information. We know "_:X knows something" from the first triple "_:X foaf:knows ex:bob" and that is all the second triple says.

Graphs G3 and G4 are lean.

If we have G5: `_:X foaf:knows _:Y` then G5 is lean but G3 merge G5 is not lean.

G2 is lean because the triple "_:X foaf:knows _:X" adds the information that there is some resource that knows itself. The first triple does not say that.

Comment: Now I get it, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a more technical answer, using the definitions and examples from the
[w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/).

### Definitions

> A **name** is any IRI or literal.
>
> A **(proper) subgraph** of an RDF graph is a (proper) subset of the triples in the graph.
>
> Suppose that M is a functional mapping from a set of blank nodes to some set
> of literals, blank nodes and IRIs. Any graph obtained from a graph G by
> replacing some or all of the blank nodes N in G by M(N) is an **instance** of G.
>
> A **proper instance** of a graph is an instance in which a blank node has been
> replaced by a name, or two blank nodes in the graph have been mapped into the
> same node in the instance.
>
> An RDF graph is **lean** if it has no instance which is a proper subgraph of
> itself.

Here is graph `G1`:

```
ex:a ex:p _:x .
_:y ex:p _:x .
```

Here is `G2`:

```
ex:a ex:p _:x .
_:x ex:p _:x .
```

#### Claim 1: `G1` is **lean**

*Proof:*

Define the mapping `M`:

- `_:y -> ex:a`

Then `M(G1)` is:

```
ex:a ex:p _:x .
```

This is an *instance* of `G1` by the definition of `M`, and clearly a proper
subset of `G1`, therefore a proper subgraph as well.

#### Claim 2: `G2` is **not lean**

*Proof:*

We must show that any instance mapping of `G2` results in a graph which is not a
proper subgraph of `G2`.  Let `M` be any such mapping.  The `M` must map `_:x` to
something (other than `_:x`).  Then the following triple will be in `M(G2)`:

```
ex:a ex:p M(_:x)
```

This triple was not in `G2`, and therefore this instance is not a proper
subgraph of `G2`.  Since no mapping can create an instance of `G2` which is
also a proper subgraph of `G2`, `G2` is **lean.**

**Remark** it seems like it would be cleaner if the definition of **lean** were:

```
An RDF graph is lean if it has no **proper** instance which is a proper subgraph of itself.
```

This would eliminate any doubt in my mind about what it means when `M` maps `_:x` to another arbitrary blank node.  The definitions make everything still work okay, but the stronger definition of **lean** seems nicer to me.